# Numeric Column in data.frame returning "num" with str() but not is.numeric()

Tags: r

I have a data.frame, d1, that has 7 columns, the 5th through 7th column are supposed to be numeric:

```
str(d1[5])
'data.frame':   871 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ Latest.Assets..Mns.: num  14008 1483 11524 1081 2742 ... 

is.numeric(d1[5])
[1] FALSE

as.numeric(d1[5])
Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can this be? If str identifies it as numeric, how can it not be numeric? I'm importing from CSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
> is.numeric_data.frame=function(x)all(sapply(x,is.numeric))

> is.numeric_data.frame(d1[[5]])
[1] TRUE
```

### Why

`d1` is a list, hence `d1[5]` is a list of length 1, and in this case contains a `data.frame`.  to get the data frame, use `d1[[5]]`.

Even if a data frame contains numeric data, it isn't numeric itself:

```
> x = data.frame(1:5,6:10)
> is.numeric(x)
[1] FALSE
```

Individual columns in a data frame are either numeric or not numeric.  For instance:

```
> z <- data.frame(1:5,letters[1:5])

> is.numeric(z[[1]])
[1] TRUE
> is.numeric(z[[2]])
[1] FALSE
```

If you want to know if ALL columns in a data frame are numeric, you can use `all` and `sapply`:

```
> sapply(z,is.numeric)
    X1.5 letters.1.5. 
    TRUE        FALSE 

> all(sapply(z,is.numeric))
[1] FALSE

> all(sapply(x,is.numeric))
[1] TRUE
```

You can wrap this all up in a convenient function:

```
> is.numeric_data.frame=function(x)all(sapply(x,is.numeric))

> is.numeric_data.frame(d1[[5]])
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be a list (based on the error message).  Have you tried `class(d1[5])`?  If it's a list, then you would expect either `d1[[5]]` or `d1[5][[1]]` to be numeric.

*Edit:*

Given that d1[5] is itself a data frame, you need to treat it as such.  Something like this should work:

```
is.numeric(d1[5][,1])
```

Comment: class(d1[5]) returns, [1] "data.frame".

What does the extra set of square brackets do for d1[[5]]?

Comment: The extra set of brackets there would help if d1 was actually a list.  But basically you need to extract the value from your data.frame's data.frame...

Comment: 1beb, for a better understanding of the difference between [] and [[]] look at the indexing section of the R Lang Def: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing

Comment: d1 is a list.  see my answer for extracting value.

Answer (score 2):

d1[5] is not a single value. It's a vector (possibly a list?) of values. If you grab a single value I bet it is numeric. For example:

```
is.numeric(d1[5][[1]])
as.numeric(d1[5][[1]])
```

So I think the confusion is between the column object and the elements in the column. R makes a distinction between those two ideas while other languages, like SQL, functionally assume that when discussing the column you're usually referring to the elements of the column.

This [discussion of indexing](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Indexing) from the R Language Definition doc really helped me wrap my head around how to reference items in R.

Comment: the list member is a data frame, which is never numeric.

Comment: Alex: what are you talking about? class(list(x=1)[[1]]) == "numeric"