# 'x' must be a numeric vector: Error from data.frame of numbers

Tags: r, dataframe

I am running a cor.test on two columns within a file/table.

```
tmp <- read.table(files_to_test[i], header=TRUE, sep="\t")
## Obtain Columns To Compare ##
colA <-tmp[compareA]
colB <-tmp[compareB]
# sctr = 'spearman cor.test result'
sctr <- cor.test(colA, colB, alternative="two.sided", method="spearman")
```

But I am getting this confounding error...

```
Error in cor.test.default(colA, colB, alternative = "two.sided", method = "spearman") : 
'x' must be a numeric vector
```

the values in the columns ARE numbers but

```
is.numeric(colA) = FALSE 
class (colA) = data.frame
```

What have I missed?

Comment: what are the results of `str(colA)` and `str(colB)`. I'm guessing the data were read in as factors or character data, probably because there is an errant character in the data that you're reading in from.

Comment: @Chase: I upvoted your comment but then realized it's not the issue (see both answers below).  In hindsight I think it's a little misleading, but I can't remove my upvote ...

Comment: @Ben and @Chase: The advice to give `str` results is good though. (I gave the second upvote).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put a comma before your selector.  When you select in a data.frame object with a single indexing variable without a comma it extracts a column as a list element retaining type.  Therefore, it's still a data.frame.  But, data.frame objects allow you to select using matrix style notation and then you would get a simple vector.  So just change

```
colA <-tmp[compareA]
colB <-tmp[compareB]
```

to

```
colA <-tmp[,compareA]
colB <-tmp[,compareB]
```

I think this is more keeping with the spirit of the data.frame type than double brace (`[[`) selectors, which will do something similar but in the spirit of the underlying list type.  They also are unrelated to individual item and row selectors.  So, in code that's doing multiple kinds of things with the data.frame the double brace selectors stand out as a bit of an odd duck.

Comment: this works as well as my solution above.  I wonder if there are corner cases where they behave differently ...

Answer (score 4):

Try `tmp[[compareA]]` and `tmp[[compareB]]` instead of single brackets.  You wanted to extract numeric vectors, what you did instead was to extract single-column data frames.  Compare the following:

```
> z <- data.frame(a=1:5,b=1:5)
> str(z["a"])
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5
> is.numeric(z["a"])
[1] FALSE
> str(z[["a"]])
 int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
> is.numeric(z[["a"]])
[1] TRUE
```

Try these out with `cor.test`:

Single brackets: error as above.

```
> cor.test(z["a"],z["b"])
Error in cor.test.default(z["a"], z["b"]) : 'x' must be a numeric vector
```

Double brackets: works.

```
> cor.test(z[["a"]],z[["b"]])

    Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  z[["a"]] and z[["b"]] 
[snip snip snip]
```

As @Aaron points out below, `cor` will handle single-column data frames fine, by converting them to matrices -- but `cor.test` doesn't. (This could be brought up on `r-devel@r-project.org` , or ?? submitted to the R bug tracker as a a wish list item ...)

See also: [Numeric Column in data.frame returning "num" with str() but not is.numeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118698/numeric-column-in-data-frame-returning-num-with-str-but-not-is-numeric) , [What's the biggest R-gotcha you've run across?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535021/whats-the-biggest-r-gotcha-youve-run-across) (maybe others)

Comment: While this does make the code clearer, `cor` will convert data frames to matrices, so this should have the same result as the OP's code.

Comment: I didn't read closely enough; the OP is using `cor.test`, which does not do this conversion.  I suspect you are correct.